# Do the eggs of fraternal twins come from the same ovary?

Tags: twins

With fraternal twins two matured eggs are released and fusion of the two with sperms result in formation of these fraternal twins. Then do the two matured eggs come from one ovary or both the ovaries at the same time?

Comment: It can be one egg from each ovary or both eggs from the same ovary. To understand the logic behind it, please have a look at my answer here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/65032/24284